# has class a and not class b and is nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have problems generating the correct selector for my problem. I want to select all odd elements with class `a` that do not have class `b`.
For example, give them a red background.

You can see by approach below. However that selector matches all odd `a` elements and ignores the `:not(.b)` part completely.

```css
.a:not(.b):nth-child(odd) {
    background: red;
}
.b {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">1 (red)</div>
<div class="a b">2</div>
<div class="a">3</div>
<div class="a">4 (red)</div>
<div class="a b">5</div>
<div class="a b">6</div>
<div class="a">7</div>
<div class="a">8 (red)</div>
<div class="a">9</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add a [Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've moved your code into a snippet so that it can be executed and it is acting as it should - can you perhaps (as mentioned above by @0stone0) create a reproducible example?

Comment: It seems that you first reorderded the items with `.a:not(.b)` and give the result to `nth-child`. Try this `.a:nth-child(odd):not(.b)` to look for odd items first and then check if it not contains class b.

Comment: @Frits Thanks. I didn't know about snippets.

Comment: @bron That does not change anything.

Comment: I cannot find the odd repetition for the red background in the div sequence. Maybe this will help `.a:first-child, .a + .a { background: red }`